# I keep getting Javascript error messages

Tags: javascript

I think something in my code must be utterly wrong because as soon as I manage to fix one error that I found, the next one pops up.

I just managed to solve [this problem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89177/gravatar-hovercards-jetpack-jquery-error).

Now this error message keeps popping up:
[image]

Here's [my blog](http://zoomingjapan.com/).

I might have some jquery conflict somewhere, but I implemented everything correctly and I just can't see what is causing the issue.
Could somebody with more experience have a look and tell me what might be causing the Javascript error messages that I keep getting?

Comment: I am no code expert. The only time I have seen errors like that in coding is when I try to do something to a string that can't be done. Then I realize I am working with a string so I change my code. Could this possibly be happening to you?

Answer (score 0):

You have a LOT of plugins on your blog with associated javascript files. The chance that two are conflicting is always present, so you could try and disable the plugins and then enable then one by one (beginning with the most important ones) until you find the one that's generating errors. That way you can narrow down the issue and maybe contact the developer of the plugin (might be that he knows what's going on).